# it no longer means anything

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Glamour model Sarah Marie Summer currently has the biggest fake boobs in Australia, and a bra size so big (8M) **it no longer means anything**! Now, she wants to go bigger!*

Can you please explain to me the passage in bold. I understand neither the meaning of the passage in the context nor the function of "it" in the sentence. Is "it" the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It" refers to "a bra size". This could be rephrased as:

> Glamour model Sarah Marie Summer currently has the biggest fake boobs in Australia, and her bra size is so big (8M) that the size is no longer meaningful!

There must be some limit to the range of industry-standard bra sizes. I assume that her bra size now exceeds those specifications.

Answer (score 0):

**it** is the first word in the clause that complements "so small" and refers back to the noun of which "so {adjective}" is predicated:

Compare:

> ... a speck so small (that) it is invisible.
>
> ... a sound so high (that) it is inaudible to humans.
>
> ... a pepper so hot (that) it makes the Ghost Pepper seem mild by comparison.

But the adjective can also be complemented by a clause where the subject changes:

> ... a frozen TV dinner so tasty (that) you will think a chef prepared it
>
> ... a parking spot so narrow (that) few people even attempted it